# Factory pattern in Parallel, returning a new instance of a class from a static method

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel.foreach

I am writing a wrapper for a dll.  I'm using a factory pattern with a manager class for configuring purposes.

```
public sealed class Manager {
    private static readonly factory = new Factory();

    //prevents the default instance from being instantiated
    private Manager(){}

    public static IFoo GetMyIFoo(IParam param) {
        return factory.GetMyIFoo(param);
    }
}
```

Then my factory handles the instantiating configuration:

```
public class Factory {
    public IFoo GetMyIFoo(IParam param) {
        IFoo foo = new Foo(param);
        foo.SetConfiguration(this.Configuration, this);
        return foo;
    }
}
```

In my parallel foreach:

```
Parallel.ForEach(fooThings, (fooThing, state) => {
    using(var foo = Manager.GetMyIFoo(fooThing)) {
        foo.MyDllMethods(); //throws an error in parallel
    }
});
```

My code works fine in a vanilla `foreach`, but I'm getting AccessViolationException when ran under `Parallel.ForEach`:

> Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an
>   indication that other memory is corrupt.

If I step through the error with `F10`, I get the best clue is from the DLL itself:

> You can operate on an instance only in the thread which created it.

What is happening?

Comment: foo.SetConfiguration(this.Configuration, this);  I think 'this' is the problem. You tried to share an instance created by one thread since you have a static variable of the factory

Comment: @DanHunex What is the fix?  Instantiate `Factory` outside?

Comment: `What is happening?` You're operating on instances on threads other than the thread that created them.  Don't use instances from multiple threads, since apparently they aren't built to handle it properly (as is the case for almost all objects.)

Comment: You will need to understand the threading requirements of the library that you're using. I don't think we can help you with that. You will need to read the documentation, read the source code or contact the authors of the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I stated in my comment, foo.SetConfiguration(this.Configuration, this); I think 'this' is the problem. You are sharing an instance created by one thread with another thread since you have a static variable in the manager

```
public sealed class Manager
    {
        //prevents the default instance from being instantiated
        private Manager() { }

        public static IFoo GetMyIFoo(IParam param)
        {

            Factory factory = new Factory();
            return factory.GetMyIFoo(param);
        }
    }
```